# How to *intuitively* understand that $I(R/J) = (I + J)/J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Suppose $R$ is an unital commutative ring and $I, J$ are two ideals of it.

Most proofs of this that I've seen appear like symbol-pushing with much justification.

For instance, take this proof that I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492608/for-two-ideals-i-and-j-prove-that-ir-j-ij-j?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment5148801_2492608):

$$I(R/J) \overset{1}{=} I((R + J)/J) \overset{2}{=} (I + IJ + J)/J \overset{3}{=} (I + J)/J$$

How do you *justify* equality 2 without first even defining an action of the elements of $I$ on the elements of $(R + J)/J$? If there's an implicit action being used, what is it exactly and why?

I'd be grateful if someone can give an intuitive explanation of the jump in step 2. It would also be nice to know other more natural-looking approaches to this problem.

Comment: Concerning your title question: Intuition comes with explicit examples. Take $R=\Bbb Z$ first.

Comment: It is explained in my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388870/why-is-r-j-ir-j-isomorphic-to-r-ij-as-r-modules. Intuitively it is because  $x+J=x(1+J)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Let's consider $(3\mathbb Z)(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)$. How do you think of this?

Comment: @markvs Is $x(1 + J) = x + J$ because you've implicitly defined an action of $x$ on $(1 + J)$ as $x.1 + J$? I think that's my main point of confusion. It's not clear to me how an element $x \in I$ should *act on* an element $1 + J$ in $R/J$.

Comment: I guess if we define the action of $I$ on $R/J$ as $x.(r + J) := x.r + J$ then this makes sense, but can someone confirm this? (This probably makes sense because we're thinking of $R/J$ as an $R$-module.)

Comment: That is the definition of product of cosets $(u+J)(v+J)=uv+J$ for every ideal $J$. Actions (of what on what?) are irrelevant here.

Comment: @markvs Well, $x \in I$ **is not a coset** as far as I understand? When you write $x(r + J)$ where $r + J \in R/J$, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: $R/J$ is an $R$-module with multiplication $x(a+J)=xa+J$. The correctness comes from the product of cosets.

Comment: @markvs I see. What do you mean by "The correctness comes from the product of cosets" though? The correctness of what?

Comment: That the multiplication is well defined: if $a+J=b+J$ then $x(a+J)=x(b+J)$.

Comment: @markvs Uh, I don't see how you'd show $x(a + J) = x(b + J)$ using the concept of product of cosets. Could you explain?

Comment: You better try doing it yourself.

Comment: @markvs I don't see a way to use the product of cosets. If I were to show well-definedness it myself I'd probably approach it like this: $\\a + J = b + J \implies a - b \in J \implies x(a - b) \in J \implies ax - bx \in J \\ \implies ax + J = bx + J \implies x(a + J) = x(b + J)$. I don't see how this uses the concept of product of cosets.